# css and Html on active

Tags: html, css

HTML code

```
<div class="pagenav">
 <ul id="m" class="menu">
   <li>
          <a href="#">
               <strong>Home</strong>
           </a>
  </li>

   <li>
          <a href="#">
               <strong>Home</strong>
           </a>
  </li>
...
```

a. I am using the css code below to change the color on active, what am I doing wrong?

```
.menu li a strong:active{color:#fff !important;}
```

b. the code below works, the greater symbol ">" does it mean all li after menu class? am I correct?

```
.menu > li a strong:hover {color:#fff !important;}
```

thank you

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? :active is for when the user clicks the link :hover is for the mouseover event

Comment: hover works, active doesnt, I will try the code below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two things wrong with your code. First of all you need to lay it out like so

```
.menu li a:active strong{color:#00f !important;}
```

Secondly you need to use `a` CSS in the correct order. You have them the wrong way around currently. This is the correct way:

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/XfsvV/

```
.menu > li a:hover strong {color:#fff !important;}
.menu li a:active strong{color:#00f !important;}
```

The order should follow this context:

```
a:link
a:visited
a:hover
a:active
```

Comment: thank you! when you say order should follow, you mean order in the css file? e.g a:active cannot be before a.hover in the css file?

Comment: @Ben You're welcome. Thats correct, when setting  states of a `a` element you need to ensure the states are ordered correctly for that element.

Comment: just to clarify symbol ">" mean all li after menu class? correct?

Answer (score 0):

It should be `.menu li a:active strong` and `.menu > li a:hover strong`